# LLVM intrinsic to initialize array of doubles?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

If there is such a thing as `@llvm.memset.p0i8.f64`? I've seen some [commit messages](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-September/117214.html) and discussions mentioning it but I could not find it mentioned anywhere in LLVM source code.

If it is not present, what is the best way to initialize an array of 64-bit floats? Writing a loop seems a bit inefficient...

Comment: If you want compile-time initialization, you have to use constant array initializer (`[float 1.0, float 2.0, ...]`) anyways. If you are initializing at the runtime, I doubt the loop would make it worse. It'll probably be optimized.